# C# Webcontrol Click Javascript Button problems

Tags: javascript, c#, button, invoke, web-controls

I read many posts but my problem is not really solved. I hope you can help me.

Problem:
In my C# Application I use a webcontrol and navigate through a website. This works good except for buttons. I want to click them, but it does not work 100%:

```
webBrowser1.Document.All["dnn_ctr423_View_img_filter"].InvokeMember("click");
```

or

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("dnn_ctr423_View_img_filter").InvokeMember("click");
```

The button seems to be clicked but the mask which pops by the button is instantly closing after my code. (it looks like the button is clicked instantly a second time to close it)

So I readed many and make try and error. Here is some code which made the click and the mask dont close after click. But the code seems to pause because after this clicks nothing happens:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("dnn_ctr423_View_img_filter").InvokeMember("click");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("dnn_ctr423_View_img_filter").RaiseEvent("click");
```

Maybe the mask dont closes because the program pauses.

Anyone who understand this behaviour?

If I hover the button I get - `javascript:void(0);` (Firefox)

I really thanks anyone for help

Comment: I see someone is attempting to edit your question already.. please accept his/her edit... then clearify whether this **exceptional** button (which isn't behaving like the other navigation buttons) is because you're attempting to use it as a toggle button.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help. Yes you are right. This button works like a toggle button. I can understand your thoughts but I do not know how to solve this. If I google for "C# webcontrol click toggle button" I do not find anything which helps me. I thought that a click is a click. Nothing matter on which element? Is there no command which makes a stupid click on my element?